# Run a microsoft azure virtual-machines as a SSH Server and connect a android client using JSCH /SSHD over mobile internet is it possible?

Tags: networking, ssh, freesshd

i want to setup a SSH server on  microsoft azure vm then i like to upload and downloads file from the server to my android mobile over mobile internet is it possible? if it dose how can i setup this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is too broad. its not one question, its 1001+. yes what you want is possible. we cannot tell you everything involved in establishing infrastructure in azure and installing/configuring the required software.

Comment: @FrankThomas this a yes or no question i just want to know this is possible  or  too hard or simple task  achieve thats all i want to know

Comment: I'm sure i could pull it off, so yes, it is feasible.